# Git - Push uncommitted changes to previous commit

Tags: git

How can i push/move uncommitted changes to previous commit to avoid to create a new commit for very small changes?

Comment: `git add <<file to be added>>` then `git commit --amend`

Comment: That would be a history rewrite, avoid doing it you already pushed commits to a remote. If the commits are still local you could do a rebase or a fixup+rebase or an ammend if you want to change the *last* commit.

Answer (score -1):

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

This command will just undo last commit without removing the changes and allows other uncommitted changes to be push into one commit. So that required changes can be bind and move into a single commit.